# The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (nested reply)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

```
getString(comment) {
const authorName = comment.getAuthor().getName();
if (!comment.getRepliedTo()) return authorName;
return `${comment.getMessage()} by ${authorName} (replied to 
${this.getString(comment.getRepliedTo())})`;
}
toString() {
const authorName = this.getAuthor().getName();
if (!this.getRepliedTo()) {
return `${this._message} by ${authorName}`;
}
return this.getString(this);
}
}
```

Help please, it keeps giving me this error.

The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (nested reply)

Comment: As far as i know toString() has to be called on a object. Which means that in your case it would probably return "Object undefined". Try this context "ObjectyouwanttoString.toString()"

Comment: The thing is that-- these formats must be followed.

Comment: No replied to:
message + " by " + author.name
With replied to:
message + " by " + author.name + " (replied to " + repliedTo.author.name + ")"